# custom test Reporter In ruby for failures and passed steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, report

I want to ask if anybody has an idea about a ruby reporter , what I want is a framework for reporter HTML or XML report to give me a status for each step and the whole test cases in my test..

Comment: `cucumber` is the tool http://cukes.info/reports.html

Comment: I know about cucumber but what I want is not BDD framework , I want an XML reporter any idea?

Comment: cucumber genearte JUNIT report which is pure xml report JUnit

This report generates XML files just like Apache Ant’s junitreport task. This XML format is understood by most Continuous Integration servers, who will use it to generate visual reports.

Comment: or you can try `rspec` like this way `rspec <path_to_spec_file> --format xml`

Comment: can i put a step failure status or passed status after each step in my ruby test ?

Comment: I am a little bit confused about how to to use rspec files to test test cases that already have been written in ruby, each step represent a method , and a class represent the page